# SNS aws not working properly

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, amazon-sns

Hello all i wrote an application grabbing photos from facebook. I did that successfully. Now i wrote a notification service using SNS in java. Basically sending out subscription for first time users who log into my application and also when a pictured has been deleted from the repository. My first problem is when i download the pics and user info from facebook, i want to check if its a new user or not. If a new user send out a subscription and if not(basically user exist in mongoDb dont send out email for subscription) but my code keeps sending out email to everyuser. And lastly when a user deletes a photo they get a notification but when i tested it i failed to get an email. Below is my code could someone tell me what im doing wrong.

```
public class EmailNotifications {

private static final String accessKey = "****************";
private static final String secretAccess ="***********************";

 //Notification when user gets info from facebook app for first time. 
public static void SignUP(String email, String Topic){
    AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretAccess));
    snsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_1));

    //create a Topic
    CreateTopicRequest createTopicRequest = new CreateTopicRequest().withName(Topic);
    CreateTopicResult createTopicResult = snsClient.createTopic(createTopicRequest);

    //subscribes to a topic
    SubscribeRequest subscribeRequest = new SubscribeRequest().withTopicArn(createTopicResult.getTopicArn())
                                                                .withProtocol("email").withEndpoint(email);
   snsClient.subscribe(subscribeRequest);

}
//Notification when photo is deleted
public static void deletePic(String email, String topic, String message){

    AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey,secretAccess));
    snsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_1));

    CreateTopicRequest create = new CreateTopicRequest(topic);
    CreateTopicResult result = snsClient.createTopic(create);

    System.out.println(result);
    //String msg = "My text published to SNS topic with email endpoint";
    PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest(result.getTopicArn(), message);
    publishRequest.setSubject("Deleted Pic");

    /*PublishResult pu= */snsClient.publish(publishRequest);

 }
```

}

Below is my implementation of both delete and grabbing data for first assuming mongodb is empty:

Delete photo implementation:

```
@Override
 //deletes photo from mongoDB... but doesn't send out an email stating phootid
public String deletePhoto(String id, String PhotoId){
    String mssg="";
    if(accountRepo.exists(id)){
        UserAccounts userAccounts=accountRepo.findById(id);
        UserPhotos photos = photoRepo.findByPhotoId(PhotoId);
        mssg="The picture "+photos.getPhotoId()+" has been deleted from the application";
        EmailNotifications.deletePic(userAccounts.getEmail(),topic,mssg);
        photoRepo.delete(PhotoId);
        return "Photo is deleted";
    }
    else
        return "Photo does not exist";
}
```

Grabbing photo from face for the first time. The user should get only one notification max. But i keep getting several messages.

```
@Override
public UserAccounts create(FacebookClient facebookClient){
    User me = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);
    UserAccounts userAccounts = new UserAccounts();
    userAccounts.setEmail(me.getEmail());
    userAccounts.setGender(me.getGender());
    userAccounts.setId(me.getId());
    userAccounts.setName(me.getName());
    accountRepo.save(userAccounts);
    EmailNotifications.SignUP(me.getEmail(), topic);
    return userAccounts;
}
```

Could some one assist me on this

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your description and the code, it would guess the email you keep getting when you download for a user is the subscription confirmation email because all `EmailNotifications.SignUp` does is subscribe the email address.

I would guess that the reason you haven't getting any email when you delete a picture is because you haven't confirmed the subscription.  In the subscription confirmation emails, there should be a link you can click on to confirm the subscription.

As for why you keep getting the email every time you download, I can't tell from your code, but in the `create` method you show there is not `if` block around calling SignUp to check if the user already existed, which I imagine is your problem.

As an aside, if your application is interacting with users and you want a good email experience, you would probably be better off using SES, which allows you to completely control the formatting and branding of your email.